# Opengl -Drawing smooth circle on mouse drag

Tags: c++, opengl, mouse

I want to draw a smooth circle on mouse drag. That is on first mouse click, the start point is set and on dragging mouse the end point gets updated and the circle gets expanded. I read somewhere it is possible to draw using line strips. But that won't fit my requirement.

In short I need the logic to draw a circle using the given two points using opengl.

Comment: What does the start and end points represent? Center and radius (distance from start-to-end) or top-left and bottom-right of the circle bounds?

Comment: @ Vite Falcon top left and bottom right

Comment: @ViteFalcon please help

Comment: Well, what **will** fit your requirement then? Computers cannot draw a perfect circle, they always approximate. If line strips isn't desireable for you, it'd be good to know what else is.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you have the:

```
top-left position (X1 Y1)
```

and

```
bottom-right position (X2 Y2)
```

you also have the

```
diameter (sqrt([X2-X1]^2+[Y2-Y1]^2))
radius (diameter/2)
```

and center:

```
CenterX = X1 + (radius * (sin(-atan2(Y2-Y1,X2-X1))));
CenterY = Y1 + (radius * (cos(-atan2(Y2-Y1,X2-X1))));
```

from that point on you can draw a circle from the center with the given radius in whatever way you like!

```
double max = 2.0 * PI;
double precision = 0.1;
double current = 0.0;
struct point
{
    double x;
    double y;
};

while(current <= max)
{
    point one;
    point two;
    one.x = Center.x + (radius * (sin(-current)));
    one.y = Center.y + (radius * (cos(-current)));
    current += precision;
    two.x = Center.x + (radius * (sin(-current)));
    two.y = Center.y + (radius * (cos(-current)));

    //draw line between one and two?
    //draw here
}
```

(I won't answer further because lines are not what you want? I don't know any other way to "draw" a "circle")

ByTheWay: by correctly modifying this code you can even draw parts of a "pseudo-circle" (`while(current<=max)`)

Anyway, this is how I draw a circle in my code:

```
//draw fun
{
    struct point
    {
        double x,y;
        point(double x,double y) : x(x), y(y) {}
        point(){ x = 0.0, y = 0.0; }
    };

    point start(100.0,100.0);
    point end(150.0,150.0);
    point center;

    double diameter = sqrt(pow(end.x-start.x,2.0)+pow(end.y-start.y,2.0));
    double radius = diameter/2.0;
    double max = 2.0 * PId;
    double precision = max/180.0;
    double current = 0.0;

    center.x = start.x + (radius * (sin(-atan2(end.y-start.y,end.x-start.x))));
    center.y = start.y + (radius * (cos(-atan2(end.y-start.y,end.x-start.x))));
    //render->BeginRender();
    while(current <= max)
    {
        point one;
        //point two;
        one.x = center.x + (radius * (sin(-current)));
        one.y = center.y + (radius * (cos(-current)));
        render->D3DBox((float)one.x,(float)one.y,1.0f,1.0f,0xFFFFFFFF);//create a dot
        current += precision;
        //two.x = center.x + (radius * (sin(-current)));
        //two.y = center.y + (radius * (cos(-current)));
        //
        //render->DrawLine(D3DXVECTOR3((float)one.x,(float)one.y,1.0),D3DXVECTOR3((float)two.x,(float)two.y,1.0),0xFFFFFFFF);
    }
    //render->EndRender();
}
```

output:

[image]